# I tried to request body json to node js using await fetch the body is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new in node js so I tried to req fetch json post to node js using this code:

```
const req = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin", {
      method: "POST",
      header:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username:myusername,
        password:mypassword
      })
    },
    
  )
```

But when I check in server side the body is empty, is there something that I missed?

This is my server side code:

```
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
    db.findByUsername(req.body.username,(err,data) =>{
        if(err){
            if (err.kind === "not_found") {
              res.status(404).send({
                message: `Not found customer with username or password.`
              });
            } else {
              res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error retrieving Customer with id " + req.body.username
              });
            }
        
          }
        console.log(data)
        if(data.password_user != req.body.password){
            return res.status(401).send({
                accessToken: null,
                message: "Invalid Password!"
              });

        }
     
    });
  
};
```

I tried to access with `req.body.username` but it's empty.

This is my route:

```
const { verifySignUp } = require("../middleware");
const controller = require("../controllers/auth.controller");

const bodyParser = require('express');


module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.post("/api/auth/signin", controller.signin);
};
```

This is the error code:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'password_user' of null
```

Comment: Please show your server side as well.

Comment: Are you using bodyParser?

Comment: no i didnt, but when i try the code in postman it work

Comment: Just use FormData in body  ! Everything will work perfectly. Moreover try catching the error

Comment: @Sanmeet I'm not so sure. This seems like a server-size problem...

Comment: @Sanmeet ive tried to use formData but it doens work too

Comment: i treid to add var bodyParser = require('body-parser') to my route but its still error @code

Comment: Have you added `app.use(bodyParser.json())`? Please include your main code.

Comment: i did, i already added my route code

Comment: Well, I've never seen that syntax, so I'm not sure if it works. How about, right before your routes, include `app.use(bodyParser.json());`?

Comment: i just did it but it doesnt work too

Comment: if this is express you need bodyparser. Also please tag your question with express in that case.

Comment: @TheFool can you suggest where i need to add bodyparser, beacuse i already added it in route

Comment: Add `bodyParser` separately: `app.use(bodyParser.json())` just after your handler for CORS and before your post route handler.

Comment: Also in your CORS handler, your second header key is missing; should be: `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Headers here,...`

Comment: i updated my code , but its still doesn work, i updated it too in above, cann you tell me where i get wrong please, im stuck for 5 hours just to find the solution for this @AbrarHossain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the way you are adding the a middleware is wrong (I have never seen that to be honest). Here's what I was aiming to explain:

```js
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        // CORS handler
    });
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use('/api/auth/signin', controller.signin);
};
```

Also note the fact that your import is wrong:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

If I understand correctly, you want to patch your `app` which is an instance of an express application. In that case, you should add the `body-parser` middleware right before you add any handlers for `POST` and `PUT` request. Otherwise, the order of execution is wrong and the raw body from the request is never parsed and hence, `req.body` is `undefined`.

**Edit**

If you want to use `body-parser` for a single route, you can try the following:

`app.route('/path/to', bodyParser.json(), function(req,res,next) { });`

Comment: guys thank you so much for that helps , i typo in header it should be headers and thank you for the explaination i appreciate a lot